# generate multiple class objects

Tags: c#, list, file, loops, class

I'm trying to generate multiple class objects but I get a "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range." message at this line: clients[i] = new IRCClient(credentials, textEdit1.Text);

```
  public void FileRead()
    {
        if (File.Exists(AccountsFile))
        {
            Account.Clear();
            using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(AccountsFile))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = Reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Account.Add(new Accounts { Username = line.Split(':')[0], Password = line.Split(':')[1] });
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            File.Create(AccountsFile);
        }
    }

   private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clients = new List<IRCClient>();
        int num = 7;
        foreach (var acc in Account)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                credentials = new ConnectionCredentials(acc.Username, acc.Password);
                clients[i] = new IRCClient(credentials, textEdit1.Text); //exception thrown
                clients.Add(clients[i]);
                foreach (var c in clients)
                {
                    c.Connect();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how lists work. Remove your indexer (the line that throws), and directly add the object: `clients.Add(new IRCClient(credentials, textEdit1.Text));`

Comment: Though even with that, your code doesn't make much sense. Do you really mean to add 7 times the number of accounts? Where does that 7 even comes from?

Comment: @KevinGosse Because I'm trying to connect 7 bots to an IRC chat channel from a text file lol.

Comment: Hey @KevinGosse do you think you can help me a little more on discord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List<T>` is not the same as T[]. Ie Lists are not the same as arrays and have some different behaviours.

```
myarray[i] = someValue;
```

with arrays this will add some value to position i of the array. But remember arrays are initiliased up front

```
myarray = new object[10];
```

so as long as i >= 0 and < 10 the above code is fine.

Lists however are different and can (and in your case) are initialised empty. And then they get made bigger as and when needed. Its one of the benefits (but can also be a performance hit)

So when you do this:

```
clients = new List<IRCClient>();
```

you are creating an empty list, that has nothing in it so it has no indexes so when you do:

```
clients[i]
```

There is nothing at position 'i' so you get that exception.

The correct use would be

```
clients.Add(new IRCClient(credentials, textEdit1.Text))
```